# Issue while printing text in Excel in php

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel library to create spreadsheet through php.. I want to print some text there , But problem is printing breaks when it encounters any special characters in sentence.

Example :    If sentence has characters such as **- ' " :**  etc Sentence after these characters are not printed.

Is there any way to escape this special characters while generating excel..

Regards,
Kir

Comment: try addslashes() function?

Comment: Show code, none of those characters should break PHPExcel in any way

Comment: @MarkBaker this is how  i am looping data and printing it to excel..    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel_rows)){
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i,$row['post_title']);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getHyperlink()->setUrl($row['guid']);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getHyperlink()->setTooltip('Navigate to website'); } Here post_title is text and its hyperlink ..

Comment: Is that data UTF-8? Is the problem with the value you're setting in the cell (`$row['post_title']`) or with the hyperlink value from `$row['g‌​uid']`

Comment: No Problem with Hyperlink.. Problem is with Value of $row['post_title']. I have to escape special characters in $row['post_title'] while printing..

Comment: Make sure that it's UTF-8 is all that I can say, PHPExcel doesn't have any special interpretation of "special chars" because they aren't special, simply part of a string